# Access method from string html using onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below I created a demo of the exact issue I'm facing I want to access the test method but I think its not binding with onclick event as on every re-render the alert is coming, I tried to do something like
onclick=`${()=>test()}` but its giving error can someone please help me telling what is the right approach to access the test() method using this

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const test = () => {
    alert('hi');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
      <button onclick=${test()}>Test</button>`}}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct problems here.

First, you have a template string which includes `${test()}`. This replaces the contents of `${...}` with the return value of `test()` which is called immediately.

You need to put a string of JavaScript there (such as `onclick="test()"`).

Then that JS will be evaluated with the click event happens.

---

So the next problem:

The `test` variable is scoped to the function it is declared within.

There is no way to access it from an `onclick` attribute which will be evaluated in a completely different scope.

So you need to copy the function to a scope where it is available.

Possibly (**but don't do this**) with something along the lines of:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.test = test;
    return () => {
        delete window.test;
    }
})
```

Then it will be in scope for the `onclick` attribute.

You just have a bunch of other problems involving name clashes so you need to do extra work to make sure the global `test` is unique.

---

A safer alternative would be to avoid the `onclick` attribute and use `addEventListener`.

Unfortunately, because you are a string of HTML that's really hard to to apply. So you can `useRef` to get a reference to the containing element and use a delegated event handler to capture the click:

(untested)

```
export default function App() {
  const test = () => {
    alert('hi');
  }

  const element = useRef(null);

  useEffect( () => {
      if (!element) return;
      const div = element;
      const listener = event => {
          if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button') return; 
          test(); 
      };
      div.addEventListener('click', listener);
      return () => div.removeEventListener('click', listener);
  }, [element])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <div ref={element} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
      <button onclick=${test()}>Test</button>`}}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

And that is *also* a nasty mess.

**Avoid** using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Just use JSX:

```
export default function App() {
  const test = () => {
    alert('hi');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <div>
          <button onClick={test}>Test</button>`}}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but the issue is that the above is my scenario, in actual code there are so many iterations and nesting also with various parameters with the function, that I cannot use addEventListener for this, I need to use the onclick event only, although thanks for your answer

Comment: @Adarsh — I provided three solutions. The first one makes it work with the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Ah, yes now I see that I did something same like that, points for that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it comes under good practice or not, but atleast for now it resolves my problem, I create a GlobalEventHandlers.onclick and using that triggering my desired function

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const test = () => {
    alert("hi");
  };
  window.myFunction = () => {
    test();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>`
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So… exactly what I said was the simplest approach.

Comment: Yes I didn't seen your first approach, but yes that worked for me